# How to generate a random sample to follow a given distribution, once weighted?

Tags: random-generation

Most statistics packages allow for generating samples from a prescribed distribution; usually, by applying the inverse CDF on a sample generated uniformly on [0,1].

Now, imagine that I would like to generate a sample following a distribution, but only if the sample is weighted (with arbitrary positive weights). Are there software products that can do that? What would be the way to mathematically consider this problem? I need it for testing purposes.

I assume providing the weights as input would lower the difficulty, but I do not necessarily want to fix them myself, I am as a happy if they are left as a free parameter.

By weights, I mean frequency weights, which would be applied to the sampled data. The kind of weights one would use when building a histogram, for instance, where no weights would be equivalent to a unitary weight for each observation.
For instance, if $X \sim \mathrm{LN}\left(\sigma^{2}, \mu\right)$ then a random sample weighted by itself would follow $\mathrm{LN}\left(\sigma^{2}, \mu\times\exp\sigma^2\right)$. So, assuming $\mathrm{LN}\left(\sigma^{2}, \mu\times\exp\sigma^2\right)$ to be my target, I could generate a sample from $\mathrm{LN}\left(\sigma^{2}, \mu\right)$ and use it both as weights and observations. That is a very specific example and what I would like to be able to do is, given arbitrary, real positive weights, alter the target distribution random-sampling process to generate sample values that, once weighted, would have the property of being distributed as the target distribution. In the most general manner possible, so it could be applied to a (reasonable) range of distribution (again, for testing purposes, for a piece of software I'm writing).

Comment: Weighting the sample would simple define a new distribution, then sample from that as usual ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen That's the catch, I don't want this new distribution; I don't mind the distribution of the unweighted sample, but I'd like the weighted sample to follow the prescribed distribution.

Comment: Could you clarify what it means to 'weight" a sample and just what distribution you are trying to characterize? For instance, would the weights be relative sampling probabilities, but you want the sample values to follow a given distribution?  Or do you have some kind of mechanism to generate a distribution from the sample results with their weights?  Note that statistical software supports numerous *different* concepts of data and sample weights, so this isn't mere nit-picking: the differences matter and the situation you might have in mind is not obvious.

Comment: @whuber I edited my question, I hope it is clearer!

Comment: Very opaque, I'm afraid.  If by "$LN(\sigma^2,\mu)$" you mean a lognormal distribution with geometric mean $\mu$ and geometric SD $\sigma^2,$ then it is difficult to see how you obtain the stated relations.  If, for instance, you multiply the density at any value $y$ by $y$ itself, you obtain a lognormal distribution of geometric mean $\mu+\sigma^2,$ which is quite different from what you write.  This leaves me, at least, completely baffled concerning what you are trying to do.

Comment: The phrase "alter the target distribution random sampling process to generate sample values that, once weighted, would have the property of being distributed as the target distribution" is especially confusing.  If you already have a random sampling process that matches the target distribution, any weighting, other than "all weights = 1", will cause the weighted values to no longer be distributed according to the target distribution.  Why not just use the original random sampling process if it already generates numbers according to the target distribution?

Comment: It is not even clear how you intend to use the weights. As probability weights, meaning you would draw with replacement from the original sample using the weights as probabilities, which implies they sum up to one?  Or as integration weights when computing weighted sample averages, in which case the weights do not have to sum up to one?

Comment: Is something like the following what you have in mind? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027757/what-are-efficient-data-structures-and-algorithms-for-simulating-loaded-dice